# Releasing files after program finishes

Tags: vb.net, iis, dll

I've inherited a web application project that was built in vb.net that is running on my server (Windows Server 2012 running IIS 8).  The project relies on some .dll libraries that are also build by my company in a separate project, and will output error messages to a .txt file.  The main structure of the project was set up by a previous programmer that is no longer with my company.  I was given some copy-paste code to add new .dlls when needed, but how it works was never really explained to me and isn't really documented in comments or anything else like that.

I discovered that if I trigger the project to run, I am unable to delete the .dll file that was called or the .txt file until long after the program has finished running (Windows tells me the file is still in use).  I expected that the project would release these files as soon as the process that was using them completes.  I have noticed this behavior both when running in the live environment on my server and also when debugging on my local machine (Windows 10).

This leads me to a couple related questions:

- If files aren't released as soon as the process finishes using them, when are they release?
- When the project is running on the server, what happens if two users try to access the same .dll or write to the .txt file at the same time?
- Is there any code I can put in my project after my .dll calls to force the .dll to be released at a specified point in its execution?  If that isn't something that can be done in the code, is there any other way to get files to release after the program has finished running (like some setting or flag in the compiler or on my server)?

Comment: Look for services or additional processes which are started during execution, which may be accessing those files.

Comment: The workflow of the project is pretty linear.  The project receives a request from the user, does some processing to get inputs for the .dll, calls the .dll, processes the output of the .dll, and sends a response to the user.  Even after the response is sent, the .dll is still locked.  The .txt file is only written to by the .dll (the web app doesn't use it itself).  To my knowledge, there shouldn't be any additional processes using the files.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that both the dll *and* the text file are locked leads me to believe that the original programmer may have forgotten to close/dispose their file handlers. The easiest way is to either a) if you have access to the source, add the line to close the file, or b) use DotPeek from JetBrains to decompile the dll and see if you can id the problem from there.
As for only permitting one usage of a certain block of code at a time, consider using the `Monitor.Enter()` and `Monitor.Exit()` functions in the `System.Threading` namespace to "lock" the block of code for one user at a time. If you are familiar with Debian, this is similar in philosophy to how dpkg stops two programs from being installed/removed/etc at the same time.
If you want to manually kill a process, try `Array.ForEach(Process.GetProcessesByName("PROCESS NAME HERE"), Sub(x) x.Kill())`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I thought this had put me on the right track, but I came up to another stumbling block.  I need to figure out a couple things on my own, if I have more questions or anything I'll update my post.